# How should i adjust regex for validate url to accept #?

Tags: regex

I have this regex to validate a url:

```
 $scope.validUrl = function(str){
            var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
            '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
            '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
            '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
            '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
            '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
            if(!pattern.test(str)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        };
```

and i want to validate this url with it:

```
http://coding-academy.org/#/contact
```

if i apply this url to the function, returns false,

Problem is the #, How should i make this work?

Comment: Maybe add [;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-#] instead of [;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-] in query string

Comment: Nope, an error occured

Comment: You realize your regex doesn't match `http://coding-academy.org/contact` either?

Comment: It does, i just checked it

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Okay, my bad, copy/paste error. Here's a copyable regex if anyone needs it... `^(https?:\/\/)?((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))(\:\d+)?(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*(\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?(\#[-a-z\d_]*)?$`

Comment: errors still, im using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `port and path` part of the regex, change the character class `[-a-z\d%_.~+]` to `[-a-z\d%_.~+#]`.

Note that this will also match `http://coding-academy.org/####/contact###`. If you don't want that, change the `(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*` bit to `(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*|\/#)*` instead.